# VBA what is the longest allowed name for a function or procedure

Tags: function, vba, max

What is the maximum number of characters which can be used when assigning a name to a function (in other words, the longest allowed name for a VBA function)?

FYI, the longest allowed name for a Module is 31 (Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5 in Excel 2003).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested it - it's 255 characters...